# I want my ol bullets to appear like i) using wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using wordpress and I want my bullets to appear like
i)
ii)
iii)
its the brackets actually that I'm looking for.

Comment: What have *you* tried? What worked? What didn't?

Answer (score 2):

*[ Edited & fixed. Thanks, Mike Miller! ]*

You can use CSS counters :)

```
ul {
    counter-reset: items 0;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li:before {
    counter-increment: items 1;  
        content: counter(items, lower-roman) ") ";
}
```

You can see live how this works at http://dabblet.com/gist/2724823

Comment: Won't the ) appear after the content in the li not the indicator?

Comment: Ooops, true, I'm changing it now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is

```
li:before { content: ")" };
```

And then set a negative left margin.

Answer (score 0):

If the specific numbering style is essential, make it part of the content and either suppress default browser-generated numbers or don’t use `ul` markup at all, e.g.

```
<div>i) first item</div>
```

or (if you may need to style the numbers

```
<div><span class=num>i)</span> first item</div>
```

You can alternative generate the numbers using CSS (generated content and `:before` pseudoelements), but it’s clumsier, especially if you need to ensure reasonable presentation on all browsers.